# How can we just take the value of group names with vuejs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, lodash

I have an array checking for a REST API and which includes group names and group names include keys and values. I want to take just values of keys. Because keys in group names and values in keys.  I just wanna see the values on the network side in properties.

I tried to use lodash components like a grubby,reduce,and omit etc. but ı couldnt make it work.

Comment: wouldn't using a .map in return work?

Comment: Welcome to SO! source data as text and desired data as text would be really helpful to us

Comment: Dear Hamilton, Gabriel, ı tried, but not working

Comment: Please post your array in order to better help you out.

Comment: I did it with Object.entries() method. Thank you so much for your interest to all you guys..